# How to find all "Parentid" quetsions that a single users posts are connected to?

Tags: xml, notepad++

In an xml data dump  of one of the stackexchange sites (like this one)   I want to find all the answers a specific user has written and also all the questions they answered

I have found all their answers by searching for "OwnerUserID="x"      from the very massive amount of lines of questions/answers by different people ......     but now I want to find all the questions this user has answered   -       and every answer (which has "PostTypeID="2"  - and questions have "1")   has also a tag "ParentID"

I am using notepad++

This are a few lines as an example ,  I have changed the content of the body tag with "answer/question"  and titles with "title"  ...  (notice that last line (row 28)  is the answer to the first line (row 13) because its parentid is 13  :

```xml
<row Id="13" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T09:38:43.457" Score="4" ViewCount="142" Body="&lt;p&gt;one question;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="67" LastEditorUserId="254" LastEditDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" LastActivityDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" Title="title" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;faq&gt;&lt;allowed-questions&gt;&lt;tags&gt;&lt;traditions&gt;" AnswerCount="3" CommentCount="0" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="14" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T10:53:37.200" Score="-3" Body="&lt;p&gt;another question.&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="106" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T10:53:37.200" CommentCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="15" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="7" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:00:53.940" Score="3" Body="&lt;p&gt;an answer/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="18" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T13:00:53.940" CommentCount="2" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />    
<row Id="16" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="11" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:07:20.333" Score="1" Body="&lt;p&gt;I answer.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="40" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T13:07:20.333" CommentCount="0" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" /> 
<row Id="17" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:31:36.430" Score="4" ViewCount="159" Body="&lt;p&gt;answer&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="67" LastEditorUserId="254" LastEditDate="2014-10-10T19:58:18.847" LastActivityDate="2014-10-10T19:58:18.847" Title="title" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;site-promotion&gt;&lt;beta&gt;" AnswerCount="4" CommentCount="2" FavoriteCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="18" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="13" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:51:11.940" Score="4" Body="&lt;p&gt;answer.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="18" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T13:51:11.940" CommentCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="19" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="13" CreationDate="2014-06-18T14:06:56.237" Score="13" Body="&lt;answer. &lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="28" LastEditorUserId="-1" LastEditDate="2017-05-23T12:38:53.840" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T14:39:08.300" CommentCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
```

later edit :  just to make things simpler , in this example i want to find an algorithm that finds all the questions that userid 28 has answered

So he answer is in the last line (row id 19)  and if you see the parent id there is 13   (which is in the first line)             so the result of the search code should be at the end the first line

```
<row Id="13" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T09:38:43.457" Score="4" ViewCount="142" Body="&lt;p&gt;one question;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="67" LastEditorUserId="254" LastEditDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" LastActivityDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" Title="title" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;faq&gt;&lt;allowed-questions&gt;&lt;tags&gt;&lt;traditions&gt;" AnswerCount="3" CommentCount="0" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
```

Comment: Show how the expected result for your XML input data should look like

Comment: I am not sure what you mean ,  the result i want is just a list of all the lines of that users answers and the questions he replied to  (so it should look like what i put up here just with relevant lines)

Comment: What are the "relevant lines"? Show us, so we know exactly what you want rather than having to guess whether we have interpreted your words correctly.

Comment: relevant lines in where i want to search are around 2000 lines  (all his answers + all the answers this questions answered)  ........  if you want we can take this short example and take user 28  (in last line in the example code i put here - rowid 19)   and if the search equation works it should find the first line i put here (rowid 13)

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions to search for the relevant data in the data dump. For example, you can use the following regular expression to find all the questions that a specific user has answered:

```
(?<=OwnerUserId="x" )(.*?)(?=ParentId=")(.*?)(?=" PostTypeId="1")
```

Replace "x" with the user's `OwnerUserId` value to customize the search. This regular expression will find all the row elements that have a `PostTypeId` of "1" (indicating that they are questions) and a `ParentId` that matches any row element with the specified `OwnerUserId` (indicating that the user has answered the question).

Comment: You'd better to test your regex before posting. And add explanation. Why are you using lookarounds?

Comment: Hi , first thank you very much , i tried it , and it found all the answers by this user + it found all the questions by this user what i am looking for is all the answers this user gave (which i already found) + all the questions he answered (as opposed to questions his written - which is what i found using what you wrote

Comment: so i am looking for all the questions which are in the lines who have the ParentID  of the answers he gave

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood the topic. I'm not as fluent as I thought.. I guess.

Comment: It is the only thing i got untill now so it is something  (and i do see parentid in what you wrote so it might work in some similar way)  - if its done on this short code example here i gave  - and if we look for user 28 ...  than it should find 2 lines :   the first and the last one  (rows 19  and 13)