# Why i find all OwnerUserId but not parentId?

Tags: xml, notepad++

I want to find in search (in notepad++)   all lines which have ParentId="x"  in them

when i search for :           OwnerUserId=".*"             than it finds all lines which have OwnerUserId  in them

so what is the reason when i search for "ParentId=".*"            it does not find any line  (or strangely sometimes it finds 1 line only)    ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all "Parentid" quetsions that a single users posts are connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74821074/how-to-find-all-parentid-quetsions-that-a-single-users-posts-are-connected-to)

Comment: No, that question you linked was also asked by me and also didnt get an answer

Comment: [You can't parse xml with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Can you explain that and how it realts to what i asked here ?     i am using the search option in notepad++  and i found the owneruserid tag  -  so why doesnt it find the parentid tag ?

i dont understand how your link is connected

Comment: It shows you that **you can't** parse XML with regex.

Comment: Than what is the difference between OwnerUserId  and ParentId in this context ?  they are both in xml and with one it works , why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , self answer ,  i have found another answer somewhere to a different case that recommends to use

> (?s:.*?)

and i put it inside the search :   ParentId="(?s:.*?)"    and it works perfectly

, for someone like me who is not a programmer and that is not planing to use xml and regex etc except for one thing im trying to achive , it seems using regex with xml  is a great option cause its fastest and easiest for me ,  even if its not "correct" not best option for others , it still is the best option for me

this is a link to where i found that answer :

[Regular Expressions- Match Anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711971/regular-expressions-match-anything)

Apperntly  also  :              ParentId=".*?"        (difference is the added question mark)       works as well

Not sure why this things work though